# Annotate fields from intermediate model from Django RelatedManager

Tags: python, django, django-orm

Given a Django intermediate model for a `ManyToManyField` e.g.

```
class Player(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    players = models.ManyToManyField(
        Player, through='Membership', related_name='teams'
    )

class Membership(models.Model):
    player = models.ForeignKey(Player, related_name='membership')
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team, related_name='membership')
    is_manager = models.BooleanField()
```

I want to annotate fields from `Membership` onto a related manager query, e.g.

```
team = get_team()

team.players.annotate(
    is_manager=F('membership__is_manager')
).all()
```

But this results in an outer join of `memberships` back to `players`.

I know I can turn the query around and query directly on `Membership`, but what I need is `Player` objects to feed into the serializer. It feels obvious how I would express this in SQL, but I can't work out how to express it in ORM.

**Update:** I have come up with an absolutely horrid workaround to the outer join, which is to filter again, but there must be a better way:

```
team.players.annotate(
    filter_team_id=F('membership__team_id'),
    is_manager=F('membership__is_manager'),
).filter(
    filter_team_id=team.id
)
```

Comment: why do you want to specify like that way.

Comment: The existing code depends on a queryset of Player objects.

Answer (score 0):

> ... But this results in an outer join of memberships back to players.

On Django 3.2 the original query does not look that bad. At least it does *not* contain an *outer join*, as far as I can see:

```py
print(team.players.annotate(is_manager=F('membership__is_manager')).query)
```

yields something like

```sql
SELECT "player"."id", "membership"."is_manager" AS "is_manager" 
FROM "player" 
INNER JOIN "membership" ON ("player"."id" = "membership"."player_id") 
WHERE "membership"."team_id" = 1
```

(table names shortened for clarity)

If the annotation is needed more often, you could add a [custom manager method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/managers/#adding-extra-manager-methods), although this does not modify the actual query. For example:

```py
class PlayerManager(models.Manager):
    def annotated(self):
        return self.annotate(is_manager=models.F('membership__is_manager'))


class Player(models.Model):
    ...
    objects = PlayerManager()

# then you can do...
team.players.annotated()
```